# How to marge between 2 or more contacts on android

Tags: android

In my application that i write i have 2 or more contacts that i need to marge.
So i want to use the android feature "join" between those contacts to make this marge between than.

**For example**, I have contact "AAA" with an email account and a phone number, and I've noticed that some apps like whatsapp, Facebook and Skype are creating new contact entries for AAA, instead of merging the existing one.

How can i do it ? 
I don't find any example on the web or anything how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an aggregate mode(`RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE`). Have a look at this [Android not adding all contacts with duplicate fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175737/android-not-adding-all-contacts-with-duplicate-fields)

Comment: Can you please share a sample code to show how to merge/link contacts?