# How to add a new contact with an already existing DISPLAY_NAME?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

This is the problem I am facing. I already have a contact named "Frank" in my contact. I need to add a new contact named "Frank". However, If I add using the below method, The new number gets added to the existing "Frank contact".

How to properly add contacts with the same name?

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, HelperMethods.capitalize(name_et.getText().toString()))
                .build());

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
                newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number_et.getText().toString())
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL, phone_label_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString())
                .build());

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Comment: Try to add space in the end of name.

Comment: @grabarz121: May work one time. But the next time the same name is entered, this problem will arise.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer from here: [Android not adding all contacts with duplicate fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175737/android-not-adding-all-contacts-with-duplicate-fields)

Adding AGGREGATION_MODE column will work.

```
 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED)
                .build());
```